# Jinja2 Get the first item in a sorted list

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm currently using Jinja2 to display reviews (taken from a database) on my webpage, and I stumbled upon the `sort()` filter. So I wrote some code to sort the reviews by their lowest rating.

```
{% for reviews in reviews.all()|sort(attribute='rating', reverse=false) %}
    {{ reviews.text }}
    {{ reviews.rating }}
{% endfor %}
```

The code above works, but now I want to get the very first sorted items (reviews.text, reviews.rating) from the list. I tried using:

```
{{ reviews.text[0] }}
{{ reviews.rating[0] }}
```

But this only returns the first character. I also tried using the `|first` filter, but this didn't work either.

Sorry if this seems like a silly question - I'm still getting to grips with Jinja2 - but is there any way I can pick out the first sorted item from my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was simple (bear with me): Jinja2 has a [list of control structures](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures), one of them being `loop.first` which can be used in this instance.

```
{% for reviews in reviews.all()|sort(attribute='rating', reverse=false) %}
    {% if loop.first %}
       {{ reviews.text }}
       {{ reviews.rating }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```